# Logarithmic differentiation of $x^x$

Tags: calculus

Using logarithmic differentiation, the derivative of the function $f(x)=x^{x}$ is $f'(x)=x^{x}(\ln x+1)$. What is the value of the derivative $f'(-1)=?$

Is it right to say that the value is $ f'(-1)=-1$ considering that $f'(x)=x^{x}(\ln|x|+1) $ or we must use negative logarithms going to the complex numbers?

Comment: This function is defined only for $x>0$.

Comment: throw new IllegalArgumentException();

Comment: You're not going to get a $\ln|x|$ like that out of differentiation.